# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' when using fast-components in a remix app

Tags: reactjs, es6-modules, esbuild, remix.run, fast-ui

I'm trying to use [FAST](https://fast.design) web-components in a [remix](https://remix.run/) application, but so far no luck.

My guess at this point is that the problem comes from the build done in remix. I understand that the build is done by [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io) and that it doesn't fully work with the esm modules, at least not in the way they are exported by FAST.

The error I get is:

```
/sandbox/node_modules/@microsoft/fast-components/dist/esm/index.js:4
export * from "./custom-elements":

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
  at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
  at Object.Module
  // ...
```

And here is how I've tried to include FAST in my remix app:

```
import {
  provideFASTDesignSystem,
  fastCard,
  fastButton
} from "@microsoft/fast-components";
import { provideReactWrapper } from "@microsoft/fast-react-wrapper";
import React from "react";

const { wrap } = provideReactWrapper(React, provideFASTDesignSystem());

export const FastCard = wrap(fastCard());
export const FastButton = wrap(fastButton());

// https://remix.run/guides/routing#index-routes
export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Trying to make FAST work</h1>
      <FastCard>
        <h2>FAST React</h2>
        <FastButton appearance="accent" onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}>
          Click Me
        </FastButton>
      </FastCard>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-leftpad-grd8o?file=/app/routes/index.tsx:0-702

Comment: Have you solved your issue? If so would be nice if you could post your solution and mark it as solved, otherwise this might help https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#serverdependenciestobundle, not sure tho 

Answer (score 1):

based on [remix docs](https://remix.run/docs/en/1.15.0/file-conventions/remix-config#serverdependenciestobundle), to solve the problem, you have to add the following to your `remix.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  serverDependenciesToBundle: [
    ...
    "@microsoft/fast-components",
    ...
  ],
};
```